# Align data from one column with variable number of rows by position with another column

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is there a way to align data that has a variable number of rows with another column of data and separate it into separate columns? This is assuming that the first set in the first column is associated with the first set in the second column, the second with the second, and so on and so forth. Avoiding VBA would be ideal since I haven't used it before, but if it's the best way then so be it.

[image: Two forms of data representation]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I’m not sure how better to describe it than with the picture I added. It’s difficult to put into words.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest and quickest way is like this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rscXNUlRsH0&t=70s

by formula it can be done like this:
Except the formulas there are few more steps which you can see on the picture

[image]